# PHP - "git pull" gives no output on backtick

Tags: php, git, backticks

I have the following code

```
<?php

$output = `git status`;
var_dump($output);
die;
```

which gives me the right output, so why is it that when I do this, I get nothing?

```
<?php

$output = `git pull origin master`;
var_dump($output);
die;
```

For some reason that code is not getting executed, as the repository isn't updated after I make the call..

What is going on?

Comment: Is your question related now to the php output `var_dump()` or to git commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I was having is that the output was directed to stderr, not stdout. That is why I got no output. I fixed it with this:

```
<?php

$output = `git pull origin master 2>&1`;
var_dump($output);
die;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've come across this issue. When you are executing a Git command with PHP, it is worth resetting your working directory thus:

```
$output = `cd /path/to/project && git pull origin master`;
```

Also, bear in mind that the `PATH` you have on the console may not be used by PHP, so it may also be worth calling git using its fully-qualified path.